# Undesirable empty space

Tags: templates

I am new to LaTeX and I face issue with [CVIU template](http://www.elsevier.com/__data/promis_misc/YCVIU_latex%20template.zip). As you see below, empty space appears in the first paper page. I don't know why this happened while I am using the original template without any modifications.

Please help me to remove this space.
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That space is desired.
It is for the publisher to put some logo and article info. See how the document looks after publishing:

[image]